# Securing ArcGIS Server 10.x On .NET - User Store Point At LDAP

Tags: arcgis-server, security

I have the fun job of securing ArcGIS Server, and one of the requirements is to use LDAP for authentication and authorization for services...

For ArcGIS Server installed on Java backend it looks to be a very simple task - LDAP is an option under User Store section.  It does not appear to be as straight-forward for .NET backend.

I know that I need to set up a custom ASP.NET membership provider in the ArcGIS Manager applications config file, but thats about all I know.  I've thoroughly searched ESRI's site for any type of "how-to" with no luck.

I am hoping someone can point me to a good link or give me any other useful info on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this [link](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/enterprise-gis/details?entryID=6382235E-1422-2418-34B8-776AEA1F7F2F) might point you in the right direction. It's for Active Directory on a 9.3.1 installation but I used it for a 10.0 installation with a few modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for: [ArcGIS Server Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//0093000000pp000000)